# limit of the sum $\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n} $

Tags: limits, summation

Prove that : $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}=\ln 2$

---

the only thing I could think of is that it can be written like this :

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+n} =\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\frac{k}{n}+1}=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x+1} \ \mathrm{d}x=\ln 2$$

is my answer right ? and are there any other method ?(I'm sure there are)

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Compare with $\int_{n+1}^{2n} \frac 1  x$ dx. The limit is $\ln 2$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\int_{k}^{k+1} \frac{1}{x}dx  \leq \dfrac{1}{k} \leq \int_{k-1}^{k} \frac{1}{x}dx.$$
$$ \ln\frac{2n+1}{n} \leq \sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{1}{k} \leq \ln\frac{2n}{n-1}. $$

Comment: thanks this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

We are going to use the Euler's constant
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}-\ln (2n)\right)-\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}-\ln n\right)\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\gamma_{2n}-\gamma_{n})=0$$

Hence the limit is $\ln 2$.

Comment: thank you, but this is way too high for the level of the problem, it was meant for high school and Calculus I student, I'm sure there are other ways.

Comment: @Chris'ssister do you have some online source for generalization of $\gamma$ to different bases better than wiki? and can you clarify why $\gamma_{2n}=\gamma_{n}$?

Comment: Shouldn't it be Euler-Mascheroni constant? 'cause Euler has a lot of numbers with his name (although if you write "euler constant", google gets you the value of this number).

Answer (score 3):

The function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, hence the [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) converges to the integral:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\frac kn}= \int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dx}{1+x}=\ln 2$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}=\ln 2$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}=\ln 2$$

Answer (score 1):

**I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that uses straightforward arithmetic and application of Leibniz's Test for alternating series.  To that end, we now proceed.**

---

It is not difficult to show that

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n }\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\tag1$$

---

To show the validity of $(1)$, we simply write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1k&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1k-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{2k}+\frac1{2k+1}\right)-2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{2k+1}-\frac1{2k}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\tag2
\end{align}$$

---

Notice that the sum on the right-hand side is the alternating harmonic series, which converges as guaranteed by Leibniz's test.  And we conclude that the series converges!

---

**BONUS:  EVALUATING THE LIMIT**

In fact, using the Taylor series of $\log(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}x^k}{k}$, and evaluating it at $x=1$, we find that the series of interest is equal to $\log(2)$.  Hence, we find that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k}=\log(2)$$

And we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Set $$a_n = \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}.$$

We can use the following uniform bound
$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k} \leq\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1} < 1$$
Since each $a_n$ is positive, we have that $0\leq a_n < 1$ for all $n$. For monotonicity we use the calculation
$$\begin{align*}a_{n}-a_{n+1} &= \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}  - \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{(n+1) + k}\\
&= \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{2n+2}\\
&= \frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)- (n+1)(2n+2) - (n+1)(2n+1)}{(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+2)}\\
&= -\frac{(n+1)}{(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+2)}\\
&= -\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} < 0\\
\end{align*}$$
We thus have that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded and the statement above shows that $a_n < a_{n+1}$ for any $n$ so that $\{a_n\}$ is also monotonic. Hence the sequence converges.

Answer (score 0):

Set $a_n 
= 1/(n+1) + 1/(n+2)+···+ 1/(2n)
=\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{n+k}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
a_{n+1}-a_n 
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \dfrac1{n+1+k}-\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{n+k}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^{n+2} \dfrac1{n+k}-\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{n+k}\\
&=\dfrac1{n+n+2}+\dfrac1{n+n+1}-\dfrac1{n+1}\\
&=\dfrac1{2n+2}+\dfrac1{2n+1}-\dfrac1{n+1}\\
&=-\dfrac1{2 (n + 1) (2 n + 1)}\\
&< 0\\
\text{and}\\
a_{n+1}-a_n 
&=-\dfrac1{2 (n + 1) (2 n + 1)}\\
&>-\dfrac1{2n (n + 1)}\\
\text{so}
&\text{if } m > 0\\
a_{m+n}-a_n
&< 0\\
\text{and}\\
a_{m+n}-a_n 
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(a_{n+k+1}-a_{n+k})\\ 
&>-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(\dfrac1{2(n+k+1) (n + k+2)})\\ 
&=-\dfrac12\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(\dfrac1{(n+k+1)}-\dfrac1{(n + k+2)})\\ 
&=-\dfrac12(\dfrac1{(n+1)}-\dfrac1{(n +m+1)})\\ 
&>-\dfrac1{2(n+1)}\\ 
\end{array}
$

so,
for $m > 0$,
$|a_{m+n}-a_n|
\lt \dfrac1{2(n+1)}
\to 0
$
as $n \to \infty$
so,
by Cauchy,
$a_n$
converges.

Comment: $$\frac1{2n+2}+\frac1{2n+1}-\frac1{n+1}>\frac1{2n+2}+\frac1{2n+2}-\frac1{n+1}=0.$$
Looks like you introduced a negative sign somehow.