# Calculating the limit of $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+3} + ...+\frac{1}{2n})$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Hello everyone how can I calculate the limit of:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+3} + ...+\frac{1}{2n})$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove the inequality $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n-1}\geq \log (2)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2605841/how-to-prove-the-inequality-frac1n-frac1n1-cdots-frac12n-1-geq)

Comment: or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285308/limit-of-the-sum-frac1n1-frac1n2-cdots-frac12n) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73550/the-limit-of-truncated-sums-of-harmonic-series-lim-limits-k-to-infty-sum-n)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{n+n}\right)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3649023/lim-limits-n-to-infty-left-frac1n1-frac1n2-frac1nn-rig)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Factor out $n$ in all denominators:
$$\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2}  + …+\frac{1}{2n}=\frac1n\biggl(\frac1{1+\frac1n}+\frac1{1+\frac2n}\dots+\frac1{1+\frac nn}\biggr)$$
and recognise a Riemann sum.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very classical question on mathstack... please do some searches before asking a question !

As an answer, consider this :

$$
\sum_{n=k+1}^{2k}\frac1n= \frac 1 n \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac1 {{ 1+ \frac n k} }
$$

which is related to this integral via a Riemann sum :

$$\int_1^2\frac1x\,dx=\ln 2.$$

Answer (score 0):

> **I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that avoids appealing to integrals.  Rather, we make use of elementary arithmetic and the Taylor series for $\log(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}x^k}{k}$.  To that end, we proceed.**

---

Note that we can write the sum of interest as

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}&=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1k-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac1{2k}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}
\end{align}$$

Then, using the Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$, evaluated at $x=1$, we find

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{n+k}=\log(2)$$

And we are done!

Comment: I don't understand how you obtain the last line of the computation.

Comment: @bernard Hi Bernard.  Write the alternating sum in terms of its even and odd parts and see if this helps to reconclie.

Comment: And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.

Comment: @eee Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. If it was not useful, then I can simply delete this answer if you prefer.